# ASP Classic Get Next Date for a WeekDayName

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I would like to specify a number that specifies the day of week and then have ASP get the upcoming date for that week day specified.

Example:

```
Dim xWeekDay
xWeekDay=1   ' <-- 1 would be a Monday...and Sunday would be 7

Dim NextDdate
NextDdate= ????  <-- I want to calculate and show the Upcoming Date here 

So the above line would look like this when it's populated.
NextDdate=7/1/2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
today = Weekday(Date, vbMonday)
If xWeekDay > today Then
  NextDate = Date + (xWeekDay - today)
Else
  NextDate = Date + (xWeekDay + 7 - today)
End If
```

`Weekday(Date, vbMonday)` is the number of the currend day of the week (with Monday being set as the first weekday). If xWeekDay is in the future (`xWeekDay > today`), then the next occurrence is `xWeekDay - today` days away. Otherwise it's `xWeekDay + 7 - today` days away. Add that difference to the current date and you have the date you're looking for.